# Deploy ASP.NET Core 2.1 Preview App to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I'm trying my first ASP.NET Core 2.1 preview App, so I created a new ASP.NET Core 2.1 preview App from VS (15.6 - Preview 7). Everything runs OK in my local box under VS.

Then I created a new App Service on Azure, installed the Preview1 extension (as seen [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-using-asp-net-core-previews-on-azure-app-service/)) and setup the deployment with my Git Repo.

When I push the code from my local box to Git, the Deployment fires-up but I get an error related to Runtime:

> NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.Build.Runtime with version (>= 15.7.0-preview-000011-1378327)].

Am I missing something?

Console .net version check:

```
> dotnet --info

D:\home\site\wwwroot
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.300-preview1-008174)
Product Information:
 Version:            2.1.300-preview1-008174
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  b8df89a54f
Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.14393
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x86
 Base Path:   D:\home\SiteExtensions\AspNetCoreRuntime\sdk\2.1.300-preview1-008174\
Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
  Version  : 2.1.0-preview1-26216-03
  Build    : f2c3216183d20416568a4bbf5bb7d153e826f153
```

Deployment error:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\MyApp\MyApp.csproj...
  Restore completed in 450.06 ms for 
D:\home\site\repository\MyApp\MyApp.csproj.
D:\home\site\repository\MyApp\MyApp.csproj : error NU1102: Unable to find 
package Microsoft.Build.Runtime with version (>= 15.7.0-preview-000011-
1378327) [D:\home\site\repository\MyApp.sln]
D:\home\site\repository\MyApp\MyApp.csproj : error NU1102:   - Found 17 
version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 15.6.82 ] 
[D:\home\site\repository\MyApp.sln]
  Restore failed in 5.43 sec for D:\home\site\repository\MyApp\MyApp.csproj.
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet restore 
"D:\home\site\repository\MyApp.sln"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by a fallback to the following versions:

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
```

Instead of:

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
```

Comment: Hi @theroot,

changing "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" and "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" to version "2.0.0" will make it build against ASP.NET Core 2.0, instead of the "2.1.0-preview1-final" which is the Runtime Version I want to point at, right?

Thank you,

Pedro Cabral

Comment: Yes it will build for .net core 2.0 instead of "2.1.0-preview1-final", but as explained in https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7634 some packages are not present yet in NuGet as the 2.1 is not yet in release mode.